# Change colors in a WPF CheckBox

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to specify particular colours for the border and background for a WPF checkbox. All the examples I've seen so far seem to be too complicated as they involve changing everything - I just want to change the colors.

This is what I have so far - the colors are correct but the checkbox has shrunk (cant see the 'tick' symbol)...

```
<Style TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#666666" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        BorderThickness="1" 
                        BorderBrush="Aquamarine">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Aquamarine"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Aquamarine" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ffff00"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Aquamarine"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: CheckBox and Button are tricky and they don't use style for a lot of the stuff.  What you have seen that seems far too complex is probably necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that ControlTemplates don't work as Styles. As you can't zoom in on a particular element, you need to declare everything each time. For example, you can't see the 'tick' symbol because you left out the dimensions for the border. This is easily fixed:

```
<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
        BorderThickness="1" 
        BorderBrush="Aquamarine"
        Width="13"
        Height="13"
        >
```

But the main problem remains, you won't get a functional CheckBox. It seams easiest copying [the original template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752319(v=vs.100).aspx) and changing it to the way you like.

Comment: Thank you I will give that a try.